# Saving a Record with Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been going through the Rails Guides, but have gotten stuck on associations after going through validations and migrations.  So, I have the following models Job and Person, where a Person can have many jobs.  I know that in reality there'd be a many-to-many, but I'm trying to get my handle on this first.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :people
end
```

and

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

Here's the schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110108185924) do

 create_table "jobs", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "occupation"
   t.boolean  "like"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "person_id"
 end

 create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "first_name"
   t.string   "last_name"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

end
```

Is there some I can do the following `j = Job.first; j.Person`? Then that'd give me access to the Person object associated with the j.  I couldn't find it on guides.rubyonrails.org, although it has been very helpful getting a grip on migrations and validations thus far.

Thanks

PS, If there are any tutorials that covers more of this kind of things links would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right. But looking at the schema, I should say you are on the right track. What are the problems that you are facing?

Also, the belongs_to should actually be a belongs_to :person. That is, a job belongs to one person and each person can have many jobs.

Comment: if I do j = Job.new; j.occ = "Accountant"; j.like = false; j.person_id = 1; j.save then I want to access that by going j.Person I get a no method error.

Comment: That should be a lower case p in person. Try j.person

Comment: Also, is there a Person object with id = 1. If not, j.person will return nil.

Comment: Simliar error, when going through learning migrations I added the person_id to the after creation of the Job model, why it shows up at the bottom of the schema - would this cause any error?

Comment: Can you check your jobs table to see if the person_id column is available there? And after the save call, see if a record is created in that table?

Comment: I went into sqlite3 in the terminal and ran .tables and nothing showed up, however I don't know that's the right way to check.  I can access the saved record in the rails console.

Comment: Did you run rake db:migrate after creating the migrations? If yes, you should see jobs, people and schema_migrations at the least.